# Element wise multiplication of a 2D and 1D array in python

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I have two numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
y = np.array([-1, 1, -1])
```

I want to multiply x and y in such a way that I get z:

```
z = np.array([[-1,2,-3], [-4,5,-6], [-7,8,-9]])
```

In other words, if element j of y is -1, then all elements of the j-th row of x get multiplied by -1. If element k of y is 1, then all elements of the j-th row of x get multiplied by 1.

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you get when you multiply the arrays with the standard multiplication operator?

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to numpy! In hindsight this looks like a stupid question

Comment: It looks dumb because you are expected to do a little effort when you start using a new tool and read the docs instead of using SO as a chat answering machine. Have a look at numpy 101 basic operations [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations), your question is the first example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the multiplication operator:

```
x * y
Out[6]: 
array([[-1,  2, -3],
       [-4,  5, -6],
       [-7,  8, -9]])
```

Comment: That's almost like cheating. ;D

Comment: @B.Eckles it's more like not trying by OP.

Comment: Just bringing the numpy version of the same question that came yesterday from OP in pandas... But .mul was brought as the answer, which somehow wasn't satisfying...

Comment: Sorry, I decided to switch to numpy because of increased speed.

Comment: I humbly doubt you should start dealing with pandas vs numpy speed issues as a significant problem to tackle now in your process if you are just discovering how to multiply two dataframes or arrays.